# Import-Module not working when called after a param() statement

Tags: powershell, parameters, import-module

I've a script which uses a parameter to pass details to it, and which needs to import the WebAdministration module.

The start of the script is :

```
param(
    [parameter(position=0)]
    [string]$iisAppName
)

Import-Module -name WebAdministration
```

however when I run the script I get errors from those cmdlets which use the module saying they're not found, since the module obviously hasn't been loaded.

If I put the Import-Module statement before the param() then the parameter isn't loaded. If I don't have the param() statement at all it works fine.

This script is for removing a website, but the companion creation script (which doesn't use param) works fine. In fact if I run that one it works, and if I then run this one (where the module is still loaded from the first) it works fine (annoyingly... since I didn't spot the issue in testing!), so I know I'm calling those cmdlets correctly.

Is there an alternate way I need to call one or both of these to allow both of them to work in my script?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is to do with session states but would need more information to be sure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module#-global

> By default, the commands in a module, including commands from nested modules, are imported into the caller's session state.

When you import a module from the global session state, it's available to the console and all modules. When the module is imported from another module, it will only be available to the module(s) that imported it. I think when you include Params it treats it differently, perhaps running it in a script state session instead of the global state session.

Try using `Import-Module -Name WebAdministration -Global` which, regardless of where it is called, should import it into the global state session and make it available to everything.

Comment: Aha, no I was being an idiot... though you were on the right track. Just realised, the failing bits actually needed :[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Management") which was hidden away in the other script, not the webadmin module. Obviously like the modules, the assembly is loaded to the session, so is available to other scripts run within that session. So long looking at that code, and I finally twig an hour after posting here! :(